# ggplot matrix with x,y and color=category using loops

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to run a simple list of plot to assess a correct linear regression model for an assignment I have in R. Basically out of the 11 columns, column 1 is y and different columns x = 3:11 are theta or the variable that y is dependent on. column 2 has a categorical value basically 1-9 (9 categories).

I am trying to create graph matrix. I can do the graphs one by one and that should work with the assignment but I was trying to accomplish it using a single loop. Code is as follows:

1st column is y, the dependent and columns 3-11 are the variables. If I omit the coloring according to column 2, I can accomplish it with a base plot. If I try the code above I get no plots

```
par(mfrow(3,3))
for(i in 3:11){
  ggplot(hd,aes(x=hd[1,],y=hd[,i],color=hd[,2]))+
  geom_point()
}
```

EDIT:
Here is a reproducible data

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
hd=data(economics)

par(mfrow(2,2))
    for(i in 3:6){
      ggplot(hd,aes(x=hd[3,],y=hd[,i])+
      geom_point()
    }
```

This doesn't have the color categorization but if I can get this to work I can just add the color= column parameter

Comment: Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you're after, something like the following should work. First, make some reproducible data roughly like what you describe:

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(y = rnorm(10), 
               category = factor(sample(1:9, 10, replace = TRUE))) %>% 
  inset(paste0("x", 1:11), value = rnorm(110)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(y, category), names_to = "x_name", values_to = "x")
```

The data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      y category x_name      x
  <dbl> <fct>    <chr>   <dbl>
1  1.84 6        x1      1.06 
2  1.84 6        x2      0.744
3  1.84 6        x3     -1.19 
4  1.84 6        x4      1.88 
5  1.84 6        x5      2.16 
6  1.84 6        x6     -1.58
```

You may then use `facet_wrap` here to create a grid with a panel for each `x_name`. I've added `geom_smooth` for good measure:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = category)) +
  facet_wrap(~x_name) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also encourage you to provide a reproducible example.

Instead of "par(mfrow)" ggplot uses the concept of facetting. have a look here: [ggplot facetting](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#section-facetting)

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# assuming the names of your dataframe hd are like this:
names(hd) = c('y', 'cat', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', 'x9')

# then, the following code could solve your problem:
hd %>% 
  pivot_longer(x1:x9, names_to=var_x, values_to=val_x) %>% 
  ggplot(hd, aes(x=y, y=val_x, colour=cat)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~var_x, ncol=3)
```